# EWS and calendar events

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

The EWS docs that I have read so far discuss "appointments" as the object of the code they are discussing. I'm looking to retrieve events, specifically all-day events. Are these referred to as something different? If so, what?

Specifically, I see the methods for `Calendar.FindAppointments()` and limitations on the number of appointments to receive.

Comment: "All-Day Event" is an Appointment with the [IsAllDayEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.appointment.isalldayevent(v=exchg.80).aspx) property set. That's no different than the UI - eg. Outlook always treated events as appointments with the relevant checkbox set

Comment: So I have to retrieve appointments and then filter them by the `IsAllDayEvent` property? Is there a way to retrieve them entirely based on this property instead?

Comment: Did you check the method you already mentioned? Or [the examples in MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn495614(v=exchg.150).aspx)?